# Width in Android

Tags: android

can any view have its layout width in % like

```
android:layout_width="50%"
```

as we provide in ASP.net

```
width="50%" height="50%"
```

similarly in html

```
height="50%"
```

Comment: its XML file and use layout_width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (partly), what you are looking for is called `layout_weight`. With that you can perform percentage-like behavior

Comment: assuming you want a layout to be 70% then you would give it a weight of add dummy layouts to the left / right,

Comment: layout_weight works with screen size if you give weightsum = 5 and layout_weight = 1 its 1/5th of screen size not the 1/5th of parent

Comment: @AnonymousMohit why have you removed the accepted mark? I mean the question was accept for 2 years... what changed?